# CoreData: How to handle inheritance dynamically?

Tags: inheritance, core-data

e.g., I've got three classes in my CoreData-project: Person, Pupil and Teacher. Pupil and Teacher have Person as parent class.

Now, I'd like to do something like:

```
Person *person;

if (createPupil) {
    person = [[Pupil alloc] init];
    ...
} else {
    person = [[Teacher alloc] init];
    ...
}

[self.managedObjectContext save:&error];
```

But it seems like its always saving to the Person-table. When I try to fetch pupils or teachers, they are empty. Is there a possiblity to make this dynamic?

Thanks a lot,

Stefan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your if statements already introduce the dynamic element. This is how I would do it:

```
if (createPupil) {
   Pupil *person = [NSEntityDescription 
      insertNewObjectForEntityForName:"Pupil"
      inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
   // ... configure
} 
else {
   Teacher *person = [NSEntityDescription 
      insertNewObjectForEntityForName:"Teacher"
      inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
   // ... configure

}

[self.managedObjectContext save:&error];
```

Also check out Apple's comment in the `insertNewObjectForEntityForName: inManagedObjectContext:` [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSEntityDescription_Class/NSEntityDescription.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSEntityDescription/insertNewObjectForEntityForName%3ainManagedObjectContext%3a).

> The method is particularly useful on Mac OS X v10.4, as you can use it
>   to create a new managed object without having to know the class used
>   to represent the entity. This is especially beneficial early in the
>   development life-cycle when classes and class names are volatile.